# angular js filter uppercase i (İ) doesn't recognizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 <tr ng-repeat="model in ctrl.list | orderBy:ctrl.sortType:ctrl.sortReverse | 
     filter:ctrl.searchFilter" ng-click="goToPage('/responsibility/detail/' + model.id);"
>
  <td>{{model.category}}</td>
  <td>{{model.name}}</td>
  <td>{{model.brand}}</td>
  <td>{{model.model}}</td>
  <td>{{model.count}}</td>
  <td>{{model.description}}</td>
  <td>{{model.conditionOf}}</td>
  <td>{{model.serial}}</td>
  <td>{{model.calibrationId}}</td>
</tr>
```

I have a filter like 
and it doesn't filter on search which word that include 'İ' character,
it doesn't recognize the 'İ' character.

Comment: Does it work for other characters? Also, can you show more code (the controller, more html code around) Perhaps a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/HtpcyskBC2n5XezTwbws?p=preview

```
app.filter('filterLetter', function() {
  return function(input, letter) {
    console.log(letter);
    var out = [];
    if (letter) {
      angular.forEach(input, function(language) {
        if (language.name.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
          out.push(language)
        }
      })
    } 
    else {
      out = input;
    }
    return out;
  }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately  this is not exactly what i want  my filter could not convert to upper keys  turkish special caracters (i to İ ı to I)   but thanks for your help